# error validating data: the server could not find the requested resource;

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I'm seeing the following error when running a pod. I matched with the documentation in the Kubernetes webpage and it is the code is same as the one i have written below but Istill end up with the below error.

---

error validating data: the server could not find the requested resource; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: pod
metadata:
  name: helloworld-deployment
  labels:
    app: helloworld
spec:
  containers:
  - name: helloworld
    image: anishanil/kubernetes:node
    ports:
      containerPort: 3000
     resources:
      limits:
        memory: "100Mi"
        cpu: "100m"
```

---

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.1", GitCommit:"b0b7a323cc5a4a2019b2e9520c21c7830b7f708e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-04-03T20:44:38Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.6+IKS", GitCommit:"44b769243cf9b3fe09c1105a4a8749e8ff5f4ba8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-21T12:48:49Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

---

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: yaml indentation is not correct, you can validate your yaml in http://www.yamllint.com/

Answer (score 3):

> I matched with the documentation in the Kubernetes webpage and it is
>   the code is same as the one i have written below...

Could you link the fragment of documentation with which you compare your code ? As other people already suggested in their answers and comments, your `yaml` is not valid. Are you sure you're not using some outdated tutorial or docs ?

**Let's debug it together step by step:**

1. When I use exactly the same code you posted in your question, the error message I got is quite different than the one you posted:

> error: error parsing pod.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml:
>   line 12: did not find expected key

OK, so let's go to mentioned line 12 and check where can be the problem:

```
 11     ports:
 12       containerPort: 3000
 13      resources:
 14       limits:
 15         memory: "100Mi"
 16         cpu: "100m"
```

Line 12 itself looks actually totally ok, so the problem should be elsewhere. Let's debug it further using [this](http://www.yamllint.com/) online yaml validator. It also suggests that this `yaml` is syntactically not correct however it pointed out different line:

> (): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping
>   at line 9 column 5

If you look carefully at the above quoted fragment of code, you may notice that the indentation level in line 13 looks quite strange. When you remove one unnecessary space right before `resources` ( it should be on the same level as ports ) **[yaml validador](http://www.yamllint.com/)** will tell you that your `yaml` syntax is correct. Although it may already be a valid `yaml` it does not mean that it is a valid input for **Kubernetes** which requires specific structure following certain rules.

2. Let's try it again... Now `kubectl apply -f pod.yml` returns quite different error:

> Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "pod.yml": pod in
>   version "v1" cannot be handled as a Pod: no kind "pod" is registered
>   for version "v1" in scheme
>   "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/legacyscheme/scheme.go:29"

Quick search will give you an answer to that as well. Proper value of `kind:` key is `Pod` but not `pod`.

3. Once we fixed that, let's run `kubectl apply -f pod.yml` again. Now it gives us back different error:

> error: error validating "pod.yml": error validating data:
>   ValidationError(Pod.spec.containers[0].ports): invalid type for
>   io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container.ports: got "map", expected "array";

which is pretty self-explanatory and means that you are not supposed to use **"map"** in a place where an **"array"** was expected and the error message precisely pointed out where, namely:

`Pod.spec.containers[0].ports`.

Let's correct this fragment:

```
11     ports:
12       containerPort: 3000
```

In yaml formatting the `-` character implies the start of an array so it should look like this:

```
11     ports:
12     - containerPort: 3000
```

4. If we run `kubectl apply -f pod.yml` again, we finally got the expected message:

> pod/helloworld-deployment created

The final, correct version of the `Pod` definition looks as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: helloworld-deployment
  labels:
    app: helloworld
spec:
  containers:
  - name: helloworld
    image: anishanil/kubernetes:node
    ports:
    - containerPort: 3000
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "100Mi"
        cpu: "100m"
```

Comment: You deserve a medal for making the internet a better place. I love the helpfulness of your response.

Answer (score 1):

Your yaml has error. You can use a yaml validation tool to get it checked.  Or use the below instead:

```
--- 
apiVersion: v1
kind: pod
metadata: 
  labels: 
    app: helloworld
  name: helloworld-deployment
spec: 
  containers: 
    - 
      image: "anishanil/kubernetes:node"
      name: helloworld
      ports: 
        containerPort: 3000
      resources: 
        limits: 
          cpu: 100m
          memory: 100Mi
```

Answer (score 1):

`resources` should be inline with `image`, `name`, `ports` in yaml definition. OR You can use below yaml.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: pod
metadata: 
  labels: 
    app: helloworld
  name: helloworld-deployment
spec: 
  containers: 
    - image: "anishanil/kubernetes:node"
      name: helloworld
      ports: 
        containerPort: 3000
      resources: 
        limits: 
          cpu: 100m
          memory: 100Mi
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone that stumble on this because of some similar issues. I found a solution that worked for me in the answer below. I disregarded it first because there was no way it should solve the issue... but it did.

Solution is basically to check the box "Check for latest version" below advanced drop-down in the Kubectl config window or add the following line under Kubernetes task inputs:

```
checkLatest: true
```

Link to answer:
[ADO: error validating data: the server could not find the requested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67599466/7530632)

Which in turn links to this:
[Release Agent job kubectl apply returns 'error validating data'](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Release-Agent-job-kubectl-apply-returns/639535?space=21&q=error%20validating%20data%3A%20the%20server%20could%20not%20find%20the%20requested%20resource)