# ADO: error validating data: the server could not find the requested

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks

I am facing a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58163200/error-validating-data-the-server-could-not-find-the-requested-resource). The "Deployment.yml" is applied successfully but "Services.yml" gives me

> error validating data: the server could not find the requested
> resource

Deployment.yml

```
--- 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: #{component}#
spec: 
  replicas: #{replica}#
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      app: #{component}#
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: #{component}#
    spec: 
      containers: 
        - 
          env: 
            - 
              name: AUTHOR
              value: #{author}#
          image: #{acr}#/#{component}#:#{stage}#-#{Build.BuildId}#
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: #{component}#
          ports: 
            - 
              containerPort: 8000
          resources: 
            limits: 
              cpu: "1"
              memory: 512Mi
            requests: 
              cpu: "0.25"
              memory: 256Mi
      imagePullSecrets: 
        - 
          name: "acrakssecret"
```

Services.yml

```
--- 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: #{component}#
spec: 
  ports: 
    - 
      name: #{component}#
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8000
  selector: 
      app: #{component}#
  type: LoadBalancer
```

---

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.0", GitCommit:"cb303e613a121a29364f75cc67d3d580833a7479", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-04-08T16:31:21Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.5", GitCommit:"54684493f8139456e5d2f963b23cb5003c4d8055", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-03-22T23:02:59Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

When deployed through the kubectl console, the "Services.yml" is applied successfully. Any help is appreciated?

Comment: Hi @Parth, Did you use Azure Pipelines to do the deployment. If so, for us to investigate this issue further, please share the complete YAML file of your pipeline on Azure DevOps, and also share the complete debug logs of the failed pipeline run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to my support ticket, MSFT provided [this article](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Release-Agent-job-kubectl-apply-returns/639535?space=21&q=error+validating+data%3A+the+server+could+not+find+the+requested+resource) where simply ticking the 'Check for latest version' in Advanced Section of kubectl task resolves the issue.

Hope this help others :)